# Rails 3.2 PDFKit routing error after moving app into subURI

Tags: routes, rack, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdfkit

I've got a rails 3.2 app which uses PDFKit, installed as middleware. It worked perfectly until I tried to move the app into a subURI of the site domain ('domain.com' -> 'domain.com/ar'). I set up the subURI as per the [passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri). The app still works fine, except when it comes to PDF conversion. I have an object called annual_report. With the subURI mentioned above, the annual_report URL is 'domain.com/ar/annual_reports/1/edit'. When I request a PDF version of the annual_report, using 'domain.com/ar/annual_reports/1/edit.pdf', I get the routing error: 'No route matches [GET] "/ar/annual_reports/1/edit"'. That route does exist. I can remove the '.pdf' extension, and the application happily loads the page. It appears that PDFKit, or perhaps Rack, is comparing my request to the application routes. None of which, of course, include the '/ar' subURI. So it fails.

I have tried setting the root_url, in PDFKit, to include the subURI. I have tried setting the Rails.relative_url_root. I have tried wrapping the app in a map, in config.ru. I have tried everything but crack cocaine, at this point. So, I put it to you, StackOverflow... Thank you.

Comment: Update:If I remove the subURI ('/ar') from the path, the PDF conversion works. Is there a way to tell the PDFKit middleware to do the same?